# How to find xpath for a url

Tags: xpath

Can you help me getting xpath for me for following URL

https://www.skyscanner.com.au/routes/SYD/MEL?currency=AUD

As you can see on this page, there are three tabs This month, Next Month and This Year. There are three prices in all three tabs. I need xpath for all nine prices and also html link for those 9 prices.

I have tried this below Xpath

```
//div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__priceContent__K59VJ']/div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__priceButton__BSPoZ']/div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__fromPrice__3M32b']/span[@class='BpkText_bpk-text__1H2sR BpkText_bpk-text--lg__1HjEY FlightCard_FlightCard__price__6ZsOs']
```

is giving me $126, $131 and $132 from the This month tab. I am not able to find three prices from Next Month and This Year tabs.

Thanks

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried?

Comment: //div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__priceContent__K59VJ']/div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__priceButton__BSPoZ']/div[@class='FlightCard_FlightCard__fromPrice__3M32b']/span[@class='BpkText_bpk-text__1H2sR BpkText_bpk-text--lg__1HjEY FlightCard_FlightCard__price__6ZsOs'] is giving me $126, $131 and $132 from the This month tab. I am not able to find three prices from Next Month and This Year tabs.

Comment: Consider adding this in the question with a proper format : )

Comment: Done. Thanks Amit Yadav. I am new so did not realise that. Sorry for that.

Comment: The data is loading when you click on each of those tabs. However, the data is already there in the html under `script`. You can get the page source and parse the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to get the json which holds the url and the prices.

```
//section[@class='main-section flight-highlights']/div[@class='main']/script[1]
```

parse the json to get the required outputs using your preferred language and library.

**Screenshot:**
[image]